# Keyboard stops working when TigerVNC viewer is in fullscreen and system wakes from sleep

Tags: debian, fullscreen, x11, vnc-viewer

I am accessing my computer at work  with the TigerVNC viewer 1.10 from my laptop at home.

Both computers run Devuan ASCII (a systemd-free Debian fork) and use xfce4 as their desktop environment.

Now my issue. When I enter fullscreen mode in TigerVNC (which has the advantage that all keyboard shortcuts on the remote computer work just as if I were at work), and then my local computer goes to sleep, the keyboard will stop working after waking up.

The fix then is e.g. to switch to the console, kill the TigerVNC process and switch back to the GUI.

I think it has to do with the x-window-system or -manager.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: the same thing: tigervnc + debian buster + **xfce4** (the latter is probably the problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. Changing the screen saver helped me.

What seemed suspicious: *xscreensaver* writes at startup (in the upper-left corner of the screen):

> couldn't grab the keyboard! (AlreadyGrabbed)

A similar error occurs in the case of [xfreerdp](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/issues/4036).

I decided that it would be easier to change the screen saver: I removed the *xscreensaver* package and installed *mate-screensaver* (because it is mentioned in the file `/usr/bin/xflock4`). Now everything works.